# Can you help with Syracuse $\frac{3x+1}{2}$ disjoint tree graph set-builder notation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory, notation

These expressions are intended for my first paper, so I need a critique of my notation. Feel free to edit. Here is the [*Mathematica* equivalent.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84821)

The function $\alpha$ is the $n^{th}$ integer that is $\not\equiv2\mod3 $, based on this [OEIS sequence.](https://oeis.org/A047241)
$\alpha(n) := 3 n - (5 + (-1)^n)/2$
The function $\beta$ is the maximum power of $2$ that divides $m$.
$\beta(m):=\max\left(n : 2^{n} | m\right)$
Here is the set-builder notation to define the creation of the Syracuse disjoint tree graph without any duplicates.
$\textit{A}=\{\{x\to (x = \frac{3 x + 1}{2}):\beta((x = \alpha(j)) + 1) - 1\}\wedge
\{x\to\frac{3 x + 1}{2^{\beta(3x+1)}}\}:1\leq j\},$
where $(\cdot)\to(\cdot)$ is a directed edge and $\wedge$ indicates a `join.`
Graph of 15 sequences: [image: Fifteen sequences]

**Edit** Here is my first attempt after studying all the comments:
$$\beta(m):=\max\left(n : 2^{n} | m\right)$$
$$f((t, r, i)) := (2^{r - i} 3^{i - 1} (2 t - 1) - 1)/2^{\beta((2^{r - i} 3^{i - 1} (2 t - 1) - 1))}$$
$$g((t, r, i)) := (2^{r - i} 3^{i - 1} ((6 t + (-1)^{t} - 3)/2) - 1)/2^{\beta((2^{r - i} 3^{i - 1} ((6 t + (-1)^{t} - 3)/2) - 1))}$$
$$\{\left(f((t, r, i)), f((t, r, i + 1))\right)\ | \ \ 1\leq t\leq d\ \wedge \ 2\leq r\leq d\ \wedge \ 1\leq i\leq r-1\}$$
$$\{\left(g((t, r, i)), g((t, r, i + 1))\right)\ | \ \ 1\leq t\leq d\ \wedge \ 2\leq r\leq d\ \wedge \ 1\leq i\leq r-1\}$$
Where $d$ is the dimension of a $d\times d$ triangular prism, $t$ is the triangle, $r$ is the row, and $i$ is the row index.

Does this seem right?

Comment: I'm not sure your $A$ is expressed well. Graphs are expressed classically as a pair of vertices and edges $G=(V,E)$. Your vertices I'm assuming are natural numbers. An edge (even directed) is usually expressed as an ordered pair, so, perhaps $(11,17)$ is one of your edges. Ultimately I think it would be better to express your edges as the union of two sets of ordered pairs $E_1=\{(x,y) \ | \ \dots \}$ and $E_2 = \{(z,w) \ | \ \dots\}$. ...

Comment: ... For example (related but not exactly what you have), one of these sets might be: $\{(x, \frac{3x+1}{2^{\beta(3x+1)}}) \ | \ x \in \{2k + 1 \ | \ k \in \mathbb{N}\}\}$. Whatever the case, remember that in set builder notation, the ordered pairs are on the left, but things that must be true about the variables in the ordered pairs must be on the right.

Comment: @Ken, I was avoiding `Union` because is doesn't emphasize the fact that there are no duplicates, but I will replace the `Join.` What can I do about the embedded updating of $x$? The $x$ is initialized within $\beta$, used as the first vertex, set again to be used as the second vertex, etc. I will rework this and show in OP as an edit line. Thanks.

Comment: True, union won't emphasize that, but if you lay things out right, either it will be clear there are no duplicates, or the proof for that will be trivial. As for embedded updating of $x$, there are a few things to do, but remember that when sets are laid out, variables don't take state changes. You might, though, write something like $\{(f^n(a), f^{n+1}(a)) \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $a$ is some predetermined value (here, "$f^n$" is the standard notation for $n$ applications of $f$).

Comment: @Ken, Would it be better to abandon the current format and use individual sets? Like use $\alpha(\cdot)$ to create the set of first $x$'s, etc.?

Comment: I think that would make it more understandable.

Comment: @Ken, I posted my approach, a little late because my inter-net was out. Let's find out if I paid attention.